# Relate two lists with LINQ extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have two lists of different objects, one from a third party API and one from my database - and I'm trying to link the two as a relationship. Ideally with a similar effect of how DBML's create relationships for tables with foreign keys (`Customer.Orders`).

From third party:

```
class ApiObject {
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    ... 30 other properties ...
}
```

From my database:

```
class DbmlObject {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ApiID { get; set; }
    public string OtherString { get; set; }
}
```

They are related through `ApiObject.ID == DbmlObject.ApiID`

I do not want to merge these, nor join them into some anonymous object (and explicitly list 30+ properties) - but rather to make the `DbmlObject` a linked property of `ApiObject`. i.e.: addressable as:
`apiObject.DbmlObjects.First().OtherString` or ideally `apiObject.DbmlObject.OtherString` since it is a 1 to 1 relationship.

In controller:

```
List<ApiObject> apiObjects = _thirdParty.GetObjects();

DbmlDataContext model = new DbmlDataContext();
List<DbmlObject> dbmlObjects = model.GetAllDbmlObjects();

// relate them here

foreach (var apiObject in apiObjects)
    Console.Write(apiObject.DbmlObject.OtherString)
// NOTE: ideally this foreach loop should not make a DBML query on each iteration, just the single GetAllDbmlObjects query above.
```

Comment: How are they related, through `ApiID`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter by `ApiObject.ID == DbmlObject.ApiID`, is my guess.

Comment: yeah, sorry assumed it was intuitive but i'll make explicit

Comment: If you want it addressable like this, I would suggest a new subclass of ApiObject class with an added property  DmlObject. Constructor of this class would take an existing ApiObject and an existing DmlObject.

You could then use this class as if it was an instance of ApiObject.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a `join`:

```
var combined = from api in apiObjects
               join dbml in dbmlObjects on api.ID equals dbml.ApiID
               select new { api, dbml }
```

In order to get DbmlObject "in" the ApiObject, you will need to either inherit ApiObject and construct a new one of that class, which includes the Dbml property, *or* create a entirely new class to return. If you need static typing this is the best you can do - of course you could (mis)use `dynamic` to get what you want.

In this case, you are mentioning (in comments) that the ApiObject class is from a third party library that you can't change - in this case I would probably choose to create a new type which takes an instance of both objects in the constructor and exposes the properties you need - a decorator. Yes, it looks like a lot of code, but it is not complex, good tools will autogenerate it for you - and you get the class that you need for your code to be succinct.

In case you want to go further with returning an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, you could build a "combining dynamic" object based on `DynamicObject` that then responds to all the properties of ApiObject and DbmlObject - or just adds DbmlObject as a property. I am  not saying this is the right way to go, it depends on what you need it for - remember you are losing type safety. Here is a simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic dyn = new CombiningDynamic(new Foo { X = 3 }, new Bar { Y = 42 });
    Console.WriteLine(dyn.X);
    Console.WriteLine(dyn.Y);
}

public class Foo
{
    public int X {get;set;}
}

public class Bar 
{
    public int Y { get;set;}
}

public class CombiningDynamic : DynamicObject
{
    private object [] innerObjects;


    public CombiningDynamic(params object [] innerObjects) 
    {
        this.innerObjects = innerObjects;

    }
    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        foreach(var instance in innerObjects) 
        {
            Type t = instance.GetType();
            PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty(binder.Name);
            if (prop != null && prop.CanRead) 
            {
                result = prop.GetValue(instance, null);
                return true;
            }
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Remember, this is example code. If you really go this way, you would want to perhaps override some more of the methods (TrySetMember, ...), and you most definetely would want to cache the reflection results so you don't need to walk the types each time - reflection is (comparatively) slow.

Comment: this leaves you with an object of:
`{ ApiObject api, DbmlObject dbml }` rather than an object of `NewObject` .. that is just `ApiObject` with an extra child property `DbmlObject`

Comment: @arserbin3: Then you need to create a third class with properties of `ApiObject` + `OtherString` which you can initialize in the `select of the join.`

Comment: Can you declare the `DbmlObject` in the ApiObject class, or does that have to stay ?

Comment: wouldnt that mean explicitly saying:  `select new ApiObjectWithDbml { prop1, prop2, prop3, ... propN, dbmlObject }` ?  As well as making a `class ApiObjectWithDbml { prop1, ... propN }` ..

Comment: Yes. Or you could create an entirely new object which is composed of ApiObject and DbmlObject with the properties exposed that you want (which then requires implementing all the properties as delegating members - tedious to type but ReSharper can do it in 2 seconds ;.))

Comment: That seems like an excessive amount of code bloat for the simple act of relating one object as the child of another.. it's possible to be concise with extension methods, but i think that would lead to an individual SQL call for each `apiObject.GetDbmlObject()`

Comment: If the one object is really the child of another, change ApiObject so it can contain a DbmlObject. If not, the combining anonymous object might be the best solution, ie. `new { api, dbml }`. Or if you are ready to lose static typedness, go with a `dynamic`solution.

Comment: Unfortunately ApiObject comes from a third party API and wrapper - it's not changeable

Comment: OK, I think we've discussed the possibilities we havein the language.

Comment: I just updated the answer with a `dynamic` example for completeness.

Comment: If he wants to use it as an apiObject, inheritence of ApiObject would be better in this case.